# Is it possible to import . voicecontrolcommands file through my app?

Tags: ios, swift, voice-control

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18a8m.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7X5X.jpg)

The task is that I need to add a custom voice command to the user's phone (calling it will emulate a tap on the phone screen in certain areas), the user himself can add such commands in the settings, he himself can import ready-made commands, but this explain everything to him for a long time, and it would be cool to do this for the user) .voicecontrolcommands is just the file extension that I export from the Voice Control tab

Tried using siri kit but no luck